# Convert row to column and merge same index

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe like this:

| date | id | desc | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12345 | black | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | 12345 | white | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | 09752 | black | 3 |
| 2021-01-01 | 09752 | white | 4 |

I want to convert desc values to columns with amount as their values, and groupby the date and id. It should be like this

| date | id | black | white |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12345 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | 09752 | 3 | 4 |

So, i use pivot table

```
df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'id'], columns = 'desc', values = 'amount', aggfunc = 'first')
```

but, its output is separating the amount:

| date | id | black | white |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 12345 | 1 | NaN |
| 2022-01-01 | 12345 | NaN | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | 09752 | 3 | NaN |
| 2021-01-01 | 09752 | NaN | 4 |

How should I tailor my syntax to get what I expected?

Edit:
So this is a glimpse of my real data (the data in my question is a dummy, cause I can't reveal the real one). so the problem, the num_mon column is separated into two and can't be merged (I already tried groupby)

[image]

Comment: @Mark How does that help? The answers there say to use `pivot_table()`, which they're using. The problem is figuring out which parameters to use in this case.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't post that, that was just an automatic thing

Comment: @Mark It's posted automatically when you vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: I think I was mistaken. I was under the impression that if I post a question along the lines of 'why doesn't `foo(x)` work?', and there's already many explanations on here about how `foo` works, the thing to do is to close it and direct people to those explanations. And that was what this seemed to be, hence that close vote

Comment: @Barmar what would you recommend? 

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot(index=['date', 'id'], columns='desc', values='amount').sort_values(by='date', ascending=False)
desc              black  white
date       id                 
2022-01-01 12345      1      2
2021-01-01 9752       3      4
```

Oddly, using my version of the input, using your code, I still get the right answer:

```
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
date    id  desc    amount
2022-01-01  12345   black   1
2022-01-01  12345   white   2
2021-01-01  09752   black   3
2021-01-01  09752   white   4"""), sep="\s+")

df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'id'], columns = 'desc', values = 'amount', aggfunc = 'first')

desc              black  white
date       id                 
2021-01-01 9752       3      4
2022-01-01 12345      1      2
```

Is this the input?

```
from numpy import NaN
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'post14' : ["Pengadaan Mini Excavator Standard dalam"]*8,
    'tahun' : [2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021],
    'num_mon': [1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13], 
    'program': [NaN, 0.0, 0.0, NaN, NaN, 0.0, 0.0, NaN]
})
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it. It looks like the problem was the use of `aggfunc`, is that right?

Comment: you're right, I should post something more substantial. I am just a little jaded from getting downvoted by people who like to downvote ""bad questions""

Comment: @Barmar I posted something more substantial! Honestly unsure now why OP posted this question. I'm guessing there's something unusual going on

Comment: yeah right, oddly yours and others still give same output as mine before

Comment: @biyazelnut maybe run df.to_dict() and add the results to your question?

Comment: @Mark sadly I cannot give the df.to_dict bcs I cant reveal the real data. I already add the glimpse on post

Comment: hmm it's quite hard to recreate without the structure of the real data

Comment: @biyazelnut I added what I think the input is. If you could update it so that it matches what created the screenshot, that would be great (and also the only way I can answer this question)

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum as aggfun

```
pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index=['date', 'id'], columns='desc', values='amount', aggfunc='sum')
print(pivot_df)
```

Comment: oddly, your solution still makes the same output as mine before

Comment: I checked it before writing it here and its was working

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with groupby, which should be cleaner

```py
df.groupby(['date', 'id', 'desc']).sum().unstack().reset_index()
```

```
            date     id amount      
desc                     black white
0     2021-01-01  09752      3     4
1     2022-01-01  12345      1     2
```

Comment: oddly, your solution still makes the same output as mine before

Comment: Can you provide a sample csv with the data? Also, what's the version of Pandas you're using? I reconstructed csv based on the table you put in the question but may have done so wrong.